# Spyder with python3 crashing after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I launched Spyder from the terminal. I have it installed through Anaconda and running python 3.6.6. Everything was fine until I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10. Spyder is crashing a lot on its own.

I saw the following messages in my terminal when Spyder just vanished --

```
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 2 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000003 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000003 00000004 00000004 00000000
python: ../nouveau/pushbuf.c:723: nouveau_pushbuf_data: Assertion `kref' failed.
```

Eventually I had to Ctrl+C in the terminal which aborted and core dumped Spyder. However, Spyder had already vanished before that. I have no clue what it means. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with OpenGL. Try installing pyopengl.

```
 conda install pyopengl

 pip install pyqt5==5.6
```

This should fix it.

Comment: It says that the requested packages have already been installed.

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10. After upgrading, my PC was freezing at the bootscreen and wasn't booting the OS. I read on the internet that this could be an issue related to my NVIDIA graphics drivers.

Hence I uninstalled the existing NVIDIA drivers. After that I was able to boot in Ubuntu. Could it be anything related to that?

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: Aravind, I tried installing pyqt5. It's already the latest version -- 5.9.2.

I'm using Python 3.6

Could this be related to my NVIDIA graphics drivers? I have put up a question here as well -- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088567/ubuntu-18-10-does-not-start-with-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I think it's related to Nvidia graphics drivers. There's an issue related this on spyder's Github repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help bro. I'll see if I can resolve the issue.

Comment: I downgraded pyqt5 to 5.6 and spyder is now working. Thanks a lot for help. I had reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04, reinstalled anaconda and did many other things but nothing had worked earlier. 

Spyder people had told me that this is a graphics related issue so they can't help. But they did say that Spyder 3.3.2 will be having software rendering and hence it is possible that it might work. Otherwise they just can't do anything about it.